The interval where true value can lie
My goal is to get the interval where true value of a measured value 42.12 can lie. The number of significant figures of 41.12 is four.
As far as I know the interval where the true value could lie is expected to be  41.115~41.125. However, according to the documentation, it seems to be 42.1179~42.1221 as shown below.
My questions are:

The interval where the true value can lie is  42.1179~42.1221  not 41.115~41.125, as shown below. Did  I compute the interval correctly?
How is the the precision formula $-\log_{10}(\delta/|a|)$ in the document derived?






x=42.12`4
(*δ=x/10^Precision[x]; *) (*0.004212*)
Row[{"Precision & Accuracy:",{p=Precision[x],a=Accuracy[x]}}]   (*Precision function is used*)
Clear[δ];
  δ=δ/. Solve[p==-Log[10, δ/Abs[x]], δ][[1]] ; (*get δ*)
Row[{"δ:", δ}]   
Row[{"true value can lie:",{x-δ/2,x+δ/2}//N}]  (* not 41.115~41.125 *)
Row[{"※Precision & Accuracy using the formula:",{-Log[10,δ/Abs[x]],-Log[10,δ]}}]    (*formula of Precision is used*)


Have you perhaps looked at the existing questions (and answers with comments) about this? For example: How are Accuracy and Precision related Mathematica for a given operation?

@Domen Thank you for your comment; I've learned  1)dx can be  0.001, 0.1, even 1000. 2)it is determined by precision or accuracy 3)For the commom sence 41.115~41.125 of 42.12`4, dx should be defined using accuracy(42.12``2) not by precision;x=42.12;a=2;dx= 10^-a;intervl={x-dx/2,x+dx/2};
r={x,a,dx,intervl,realExpo=Log10[x],pp=-Log10[dx/x],aa=-Log10[dx],pp-aa==realExpo};
t={"x","accuracy(given)","the dx","the interval","(1)RealExp.","(2)Precision","(3)Accuracy","(1)==(2)-(3)"};
Prepend[{r},t]//N//Grid
